# Android Project not resolve gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I am using android studio and i updated it from 2.3 to 2.3.3 and after when i am trying to open a existing project it is not gradlling. Here is my Application base build gradle file where i use dependencies like this...

```
dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

In my gradle-wrapper.properties i have mention like this...

```
#Mon Jul 03 12:12:51 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

In My file>setting>gradle.... [image: pic]

Comment: from docs: gradle androi plugin 2.3.0+ needs gradle 3.3+ ... and you are using 2.10

Comment: where should i change in my project?

Comment: read the docs: "Android Plugin for Gradle Release Notes"

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps :

- Go to your Project structure
- Click on project on left side panel
- Update the Gradle version to 3.3
- Click on Ok Button

let it sync and you will be done

Comment: Thanks MRX i did it already but it is not resolving my problem.. it gives me unreadabler network error

Comment: Did you tried downloading it manually and give the path. It happened to me once when I was working behind some proxy. Or try setting proxy if my statement is true in properties fiel

Comment: Directly go to this link and download the version 3.3 https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Comment: okay i download it and unzip at the specific location and give the path of it to the setting> gradle>use local gradle distribution : gradle home: C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-3.3.......................... is it right?

Comment: yeah little bit, Now it coming to the resolve dependencies classpath but ask to enable offline and not resolving it....

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Gradle version in either the File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio, or by editing the Gradle distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file. The following example sets the Gradle version to 3.3 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

**More information on gradle plugin:**

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: thanks man but i tried it everything.. but it doesn't help me